# jquery ajax error - how to capture "real" error text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple jquery ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: some_url,
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'text',
    data: {'fish': 'bass'},
    error: function(xhr, status, error)
    {
        //var erro = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseText);
        //alert(erro.Message);
    },
    success: function(html)
    {
        alert(html);
    },
});
```

The current alerts within error show "error" and undefined.  I tried the eval statement but Firefox kept saying that erro didn't exist.  The error area does fire every time.

Separate from this: if I copy the url into a browser or use wget from command, the thing works.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Remove the last comma right after success function

Comment: Is the URL to another domain somewhere on the web ?

Comment: Yes, it is to another url (and I realize how dumb I am - an all-night coding fest isn't festive anymore).  I will use ajax to throw to a page on the one server and curl it to the other.  Thanks for waking me up!!!!!